# SessionScope and Scheduled threads

Tags: multithreading, jsf, session, jboss-weld

In my application i have a service that performs heavy loading (parsing of different files) up on creation. The data is metadata, so wont change during runtime (localized strings, key/value mappings, etc.) Therefore I decided to make this Service SessionScoped, so I don't need to parse the values with every request. Not ApplicationScoped to make sure the data is refreshed, when the user logs in again.

this works pretty well, but now i need to access that service inside a thread, that is run with the `@Schedule` Annotation. Of course Weld does not like that and says: `org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303 No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped`

```
@Singleton
public class DailyMails {

    @Inject
    MailService mailService; //just Named

    @Inject
    GroupDataService groupDataService; //Stateless

    @Inject
    LocalizationService localizationService; //SessionScoped

    @Schedule(hour = "2", minute = "0", second = "0", dayOfWeek="Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri", persistent = false)
    public void run() {
        //do work
    }
}
```

Can I manually create a Session at this point, so that I can use the SessionScoped service?

Edit: I know, that a Service *should not* ne SessionScoped nor should it hold any Data(-Collections). However in this Situation it seems legit to me to avoid multiple File-System accesses.

I thought about making the Service to a unscoped service and "cache" the data in a session scoped bean. However then I would need to inject the session bean to that Service, which will 
again make the service kind of "session scoped".

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this work:

```
@Inject @New
LocalizationService localizationService;
```

At least, that's how I interpret the specification.